# Make Element Disappear After scrollTop

Tags: jquery

What could I add to the below code in order to make #top disappear after scrolling to the top?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top').hide();
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('#top').fadeIn(3500);
        });
        $('#top').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
            return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a callback to your call to [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var topClicked = false;
    $('#top').hide();
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (!topClicked) {
                $('#top').fadeIn(3500);
            }
        });
        $('#top').click(function(){
            topClicked = true;
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast', function() {
                $("#top").hide();
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

**Update:** Also added a variable that the scroll handler checks before showing the `#top` element, so that it won't show up again after it has been clicked. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eunX3/1/

**Update 2:** If you want to fade the element out, here's an example that demonstrates that: http://jsfiddle.net/eunX3/2/

**Update 3:** Here's how you make this work more than once:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var topClicked = false;
    $('#top').hide();
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (!topClicked && $(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $('#top').fadeIn(3500);
            }
        });
        $('#top').click(function(){
            topClicked = true;
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:0 }, 'fast', function() {
                $("#top").hide();
                topClicked = false;
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/eunX3/4/

Comment: What if I wanted #top to fadeOut at the end? I tried changing .hide(); to .fadeOut(1000); but that made the element fadeIn again before fading out.

Comment: It does work, but then the effect only works once per page load. Any Idea how I can make topClicked = false at the end?

Comment: This works great, except for in Firefox where it has a tendency to fade in and out an extra time. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: @585Connor: I'm not seeing this in FF 3.6.15... Does it happen in the last posted JSFiddle?